# Are writes of large blocks affected by 4k alignment of ssd?

Tags: solid-state-drive

As you know that ssd should be partitioned ensuring 4k alignment, because the writes may be amplified if not 4k aligned.
But I wonder if the side-effect of non-4k alignment will decrease if the write block size is becoming larger.
For example, if the write size is 4k each time, it will be amplified to actually 2 blocks. But if the write size is 128k each time, then is it related only to 128/4 + 1 = 33 blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue only arises on the first part and possibly the last part of the write, where you are writing partial blocks. For example, if you're up to position 2048 and you write 8k, you have to write 2048 non-aligned bytes at the start, one fully aligned bloxk, and another 2048 bytes at the end. If you wrote 16k instead it would be the same 2048 issue at the start, more aligned blocks, and the same 2048 issue at the end.

Comment: So can I say that the larger blocks are written, the less side-effect of non-4k alignment will be?

Comment: Yes, definitely.